# image processing with neural network

Tags: matlab, image-processing, neural-network

I am working on the topic of brain tumor segmentation. I have used ["Bounding Box Method 
Using Symmetry" algorithm](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~nray1/MyWebsite/Papers/brain_tumor.pdf) to find and segment the tumor. Following is the output
[image: output]

As you can see that I have successfully segmented the tumor and now want to implement neural network on it. **I know the working and mathematics behind a simple neural network** but doesn't know how to train neural network to work on my algorithm. In short, I want to know how to begin neural network training. Any simple code or direction, preferably using Matlab, will be highly appreciable.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: @jorgenkg I want to know how to use image as input. Something like http://stackoverflow.com/q/7845518/1979347. I don't know how to train neural network based on my segmented tumor.

Comment: I have similar question. What do you want to do with neural network?  For classification or regression, you need lots of images to apply your segmentation algorithm, and train your model with the images.

Comment: @RohanKandwal Please clarify what your input, output and desired function from the NNet is. And the link you provided in question is not accessible.

Comment: @Tae-SungShin I have a collection of large number of brain tumor images. I can successfully segment the tumor from images. Let's say I have around 250 brain tumor images and my algo can easily find and segment the tumor out of them. Now I want to train neural network about it. Any model classification, regression, etc is fine by me. I want to use nntool of Matlab but don't know how to create dataset based on the brain tumor image, segmented tumor and my algo.

Comment: @user3155701 please see my comment above.

Comment: Well, according to what I read, I suspect you don't know what to do with neural network. If I am not correct, please first describe your response (output) and predictor (input) variables. Otherwise, rethink your data analysis process. Right now, you are going backward. To be forward, you should think about what is the question you want to answer with neural networks before thinking about using neural networks.

Comment: @Tae-SungShin Yes you are right. I know the working (theory) of neural network but don't know how to implement them in real time. I want to know how to create dataset from my images and then train the neural network based on it. In short, I can find and segment tumors using image processing and now I want to do it using neural network (Matlab's nntool). Any pointers or examples will be helpful

Comment: Let me put it in this way. Forget about neural network for a second. What problem do you want to solve? What is your ultimate goal? What is your overall objective in your study? After answering these questions, you can think about how to use neural network.

Comment: @Tae-SungShin As you said, forget about the neural network, my ultimate goal is to find brain tumor in an MR image. I am able to do so, successfully, through my algorithm. Now I want to teach neural network this. But I don't know how to feed MR image as input data and segmented tumor as target data in the neural network (Matlab's nntool).

Comment: @Tae-SungShin should I, in nntool, convert MR image into matrix (input) and segmented tumor as (output) in form of matrix?

Comment: So you want to use neural network to segment brain tumor like your own algorithm did? Well, it depends but you can make single matrix contain multiple columns as input and single column as output. Each row can be a pixel or a ROI image depending on what you want to get out of analysis. But I would suggest you study data analysis first. Data analysis is not like programming as many people think. You should look into and examine data before build a model like neural network. Otherwise, the model will not reflect real data and your study will be like our long conversation so far to find a thing.

Comment: @Tae-SungShin thanks for suggestion, do you know of any video tutorial or simple tutorial related to this? Although I am understanding a little of what you are saying but bit confused too. Can you explain in terms of MR image and segmented tumor, that will really be easy to understand. Thanks a ton for your patience.

Comment: @Tae-SungShin Even if the neural network can only detect tumor images for which I have trained it, it's fine by me. I just want a start and then I'll research and improve it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Image recognition

The general neural networks are used for image recognition, *not for pin pointing details in an image*. You may design a neural network to tell your whether or not there is a tumor in the image, but it is not a trivial task for a neural network to tell you where it is located.

If you do decide to let your network determine whether or not a given image contains a tumor, you would need a huge amount of images without tumors as well. The ratio of "images with tumor" and "images without tumor" should be close to the actual ratio observed in the real world. If you defere from this ratio, the network will be proned to false positives - as it learns that a majority of the images should contain tumors.

**In your case**
If you input a MR image which contains a tumor, and want to receive a segmented tumor image, you should probably have 500*500 input signals and 500*500 output signals - and train the network to create a border around the tumor present in the image.

If you extend you question as to explain why you want to make the neural network behave like this, then there might be someone here at SO that could help you!

Comment: I understand your point, can you tell me how to use the brain MR image as input and segmented tumor as target data in Matlab's nntool?

Comment: Even if the neural network can detect tumors in images for which I train it, I don't have any problem. I just want to know how to input MR images and select target data from segmented image.

Comment: Please see the extended answer

Comment: Maybe I've misinterpreted what you asked about?

Comment: Use the pixel values as input signals! Convert them to lists and use them as any other list of input/target values

Comment: I have a brain tumor image and the segmented tumor out of it as well. I just want to train the neural network about finding that segmented tumor, next time I present image to it.

Comment: so simply speaking, I convert MR image's pixel value as a list (input signal) similarily for segmented tumor (output signal) ? Also input MR image is 256x256 while segmented tumor image might vary so how to tackle that or that won't matter?

Comment: It's an advantage that the MR images are all of the same size. You should let the output size be equal to the input size. Thus the network may display where the tumor is located. It won't be possible to have dynamic output size. The consequence is a network which is a lot slower to train. To counter this complexity, you should look into CNN networks!

Comment: Alright I am really understanding what you are saying now. Thanks a ton for the patience and guidance. Slow network is not a big problem at present. One last thing, consider the output segmented tumor is 20x20, so should I use zero() and make it 256x256? will that work? and approx how many input images I must use?

Comment: Yes, you should zero-pad the image fragment such that the segmented area would be a perfect overlay of the MR tumor - this would in theory let the neural network pinpoint the discovered tumor.  You should use as many test instances as possible, but remember to keep the ratio between healthy and "tumored" images realistic to avoid false positives. Happy to be of assistance!

Comment: Thanks a ton!! you really have been of help. I'll mark your answer once I do some testing.

Comment: Sorry for accepting your answer late. However, I must add for any future user that what you said was indeed correct. Neural network isn't made to locate tumor, I am now classifying the tumors according to some features that I extracted from the image.